# How to fix Ubuntu 14.04 update problem?

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, error-handling

I am trying to update my Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) and the software updater shows this error:

**Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems. Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f**

I tried `sudo apt-get install -f` but it shows this error:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-nautilus-3.0 libcommon-sense-perl libjson-perl libjson-xs-perl
  libtext-csv-perl libtext-csv-xs-perl python-nautilus wine-mono4.5.2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/715 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 409472 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic_3.13.0-45.74_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic (3.13.0-45.74) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic_3.13.0-45.74_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic/include/config/tcp/cong/veno.h.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic/include/config/tcp/cong/veno.h'): No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic_3.13.0-45.74_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

**EDIT**

Output of `df -h`:

```
sudo df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4        43G   15G   26G  37% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            989M  4.0K  989M   1% /dev
tmpfs           200M  1.3M  199M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            999M   16M  984M   2% /run/shm
none            100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
```

Output of `df -i`:

```
sudo df -i

Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda4      2818048 2816288   1760  100% /
none            255708       2 255706    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            253011     517 252494    1% /dev
tmpfs           255708     555 255153    1% /run
none            255708       3 255705    1% /run/lock
none            255708      57 255651    1% /run/shm
none            255708      27 255681    1% /run/user
```

Comment: Please add the output of `df -h`

Comment: @heemayl Added the output.

Comment: Also add the output of `df -i`

Comment: @heemayl Added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is due to the fact that the percentage of inode used for `/`(`/dev/sda4`) is at 100%. When you create a file, an inode is generated for that file to keep the metadata. So, no matter how big or small the file is one file will result in one associated inode.

By the size of the actual disk space free i am guessing that you may have many small files of minimum disk space (4K for ext FS). So the solution would be to remove the unnecessary files to free up inodes and then you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please suggest which files may be unnecessary and how to easily delete them?

Comment: I would suggest you to look into you home directory and delete unwanted files. Here is a command that will sort files in your home directory in the order of ascending size, choose the files that are not necessary and delete those: `find /home/$USER -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort -h | less`

Comment: Thanks. I used [this tutorial](http://superrb.com/blog/2011/10/25/ubuntu-no-space-left-on-device-is-it-a-lie-or-have-i-run-out-of-inodes) to clean things up. You are right, there were a huge folder with a seemingly random name in my home directory that had thousands of files.